# opencv ubuntu 12.04 Cmake error : Source directory does not appear to contain CmakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, terminal, cmake

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I was trying to install OpenCV using the steps shown in http://karytech.blogspot.in/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html

But when it comes to the step for Compiling, i get an error :

```
clive@clive-Aspire-4755:~/OpenCV-2.4.0/build$ cmake -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_XINE=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

CMake Error: The source directory "/home/clive" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Can anyone help me?

NOTE : The CMakeLists.txt file is present in the folder OpenCV-2.4.0 and not inside build.

Comment: Hmm. For some reason `..` seems to be `/home/clive` when it should be `home/clive/OpenCV-2.4.0`

Comment: Did you run the cmake command before with different options? If so perhaps you should delete all files in the build folder and rerun cmake.

Comment: The instructions seem at that 2 year old blog seem reasonable when it comes to cmake usage.

Comment: Yes I did try deleting all the files in the build folder but the error still persists.

Answer (score 6):

Try `/home/clive/OpenCV-2.4.0` instead of `..` at the end of the command.

Also, It's generally  easier to use ccmake instead cmake, regarding the options You are trying to set for setup.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, resolved by using the below command

```
 Try with cmake .. your command
```