# cmake error 'the source does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm installing opencv in ubuntu 16.04. After installing the necessary prerequisites I used the following command:-

```
kvs@Hunter:~/opencv_contrib$ mkdir build
kvs@Hunter:~/opencv_contrib$ cd build
kvs@Hunter:~/opencv_contrib/build$ 
kvs@Hunter:~/opencv_contrib/build$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX+/usr/local -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

but it produced an error:-

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/kvs/opencv_contrib" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I used the command provided in the folder 'module' documentation. How do I solve it?
I tried the answers here at [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153845/opencv-ubuntu-12-04-cmake-error-source-directory-does-not-appear-to-contain-cm) and a few other question but still can't figure it out.

Project Git repository [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib).

Comment: You need to create a directory (e.g build) inside the OpenCV directory, `cd` to that directory and then run `cmake`.

Comment: I edited the question to include few more commands. I used the cmake command after creating and going into 'build' directory @Zindarod

Comment: Is there a `CMakeLists.txt` file in `~/opencv_contrib`?

Comment: `opencv_contrib` module should be built from the OpenCV code in the main repo. Read this guide: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Comment: Nope. Should there be? Because in the github repository every module in the modules folder has `CmakeLists.txt` but not the `~/opencv_contrib`@kdopen

Comment: I built the `opencv_contrib` using the main repo using command `kvs@Hunter:~$ git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git` @Zindarod

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should do `mkdir build` and `cd build` while inside `opencv` folder, not the `opencv-contrib` folder. The `CMakeLists.txt` is there.

Answer (score 25):

Since you add `..` after cmake, it will jump up and up (just like `cd ..`) in the directory. But if you want to run cmake under the same folder with CMakeLists.txt, please use `.` instead of `..`.

Answer (score 11):

This reply may be late but it may help users having a similar problem.
The [opencv-contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases) contains extra modules but the build procedure has to be done from [core OpenCV modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases).

Follow the below steps (assuming you are building it using CMake GUI)

1. Download OpenCV (from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases)) and unzip it somewhere on your computer. Create a build folder inside it
2. Download extra modules from OpenCV (from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases)). Ensure you download the same version.
3. Unzip the folder.
4. Open CMake
5. Click Browse Source and navigate to your OpenCV folder.
6. Click Browse Build and navigate to your build folder.
7. Click the configure button. You will be asked how you would like to generate the files. Choose Unix-Makefile from the drop-down menu and Click OK. CMake will perform some tests and return a set of red boxes that appear in the CMake Window.
8. Search for "OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH" and provide the path to the modules folder (e.g. /Users/purushottam_d/Programs/OpenCV3_4_5_contrib/modules)
9. Click Configure again, then Click Generate.
10. Go to the build folder

```bash
# cd build
# make
# sudo make install
```

11. This will install the OpenCV libraries on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to build OpenCV from source in a step by step fashion as given in this reference: [Installing OpenCV from the Source](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/)
is to,

step 1: install dependencies,

```
 sudo apt install build-essential cmake git pkg-config libgtk- 
   3-dev \libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev 
   libv4l-dev \libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libjpeg-dev 
   libpng-dev libtiff-dev \gfortran openexr libatlas-base- 
   dev python3-dev python3-numpy \libtbb2 libtbb-dev 
   libdc1394-22-dev
```

Step 2: create a directory opencv_build and Clone the necessary repositories as shown below,

```
mkdir ~/opencv_build && cd ~/opencv_build
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

step 3: cd into opencv directory, inside create another directory called build and cd into it,

```
cd ~/opencv_build/opencv
mkdir build && cd build
```

step 4: evoke Cmake to build OpenCV,

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \ 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

If step 4 completes successfully you should see the following line at the end of the terminal, **the build has been written** to the directory created in step 3, along with the following lines above this line,

**configuration done**
**generating done**

step 5: To start the compilation process where -j
is a flag for the number of the processor inside your machine, for example -j6 means we have 6 processors available. to verify the number of processors type **nproc** on the terminal then use this number after **-j**. To start this process, we use the following command:

```
make -j6
```

step 6: install OpenCV, We use,

```
sudo make install
```

then check the version Of OpenCV to verify the installation:

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with another package and neither operating from a clean directory, to build from out, nor copy/paste the CMakeLists.txt file from the source to the clean directory worked.
I simply solved installing by conda

Answer (score 1):

file structure :
example-app/

```
                CMakeLists.txt

                example-app.cpp
```

commands

```
                mkdir build

                cd build

                cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch..

                cmake --build . --config Release
```

[image: execution of the command along with the code]

[image: file structure]

Comment: Could you explain a bit about what is happening here? The answer, as it is now, is very hard to understand.

Comment: when i was running the command  :  cmake  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch..     it used to throw me an error that it is not able to detect the CMakeLists.txt file so make it detect able i have made few edits so that the command will be able to detect the CMakeLists.txt so i have used (. . ) to make command able to detect the  file and the later command "cmake --build . --config Release "  builds your application i.e creates an executable . I have also provided my directory structure named example-app .