# Building code cloned from git failed in dockerfile

Tags: docker, makefile, cmake

I want to create a Dockerfile for [Quassel IRC Core](https://quassel-irc.org/). I want to build it from source so i clone the repo and want to compile, but i get this wired error.

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/quassel-src" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER KeinNerd <github@keinnerd.net>

# install required packages for the build process
RUN \
 apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  cmake \
  make \
  build-essential \
  libboost-all-dev \
  git-core \
  icu-devtools \
  libicu60 \
  libssl-dev \
  qtbase5-dev \
  libqt5dbus5 \
  qtbase5-dev-tools \
  qtscript5-dev \
  libqt5sql5-psql \
  libqt5sql5-sqlite \
  libqca-qt5-2-dev

# clone quassel-core source
RUN \
mkdir -p /tmp/quassel-src \
git clone https://github.com/quassel/quassel.git /tmp/quassel-src/ \
mkdir -p /tmp/quassel-src/build

# build the quassel-core
RUN \
cd /tmp/quassel-src/build && \ 
cmake \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ \
        -DUSE_QT5=ON \
        -DWANT_CORE=ON \
        -DWANT_MONO=OFF \
        -DWANT_QTCLIENT=OFF \
        -DWITH_KDE=OFF \
        -DWITH_CRYPT=ON \
        /tmp/quassel-src && \
make && \
make install

# set environment variables
ENV HOME /config

# copy startfile
COPY start.sh /start.sh

# ports and volumes
VOLUME /config
EXPOSE 4242 4242

# start quassel-core
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

When i run the code in terminal on a test machine it will complile and install without errors. But if i build the docker image i get the error .. but its the same code.

```
cd /tmp/quassel-src/build && \ 
cmake \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ \
        -DUSE_QT5=ON \
        -DWANT_CORE=ON \
        -DWANT_MONO=OFF \
        -DWANT_QTCLIENT=OFF \
        -DWITH_KDE=OFF \
        -DWITH_CRYPT=ON \
        /tmp/quassel-src && \
make && \
make install
```

i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add: WORKDIR /tmp/quassel-src/build, instead of RUN cd /tmp/quassel-src/build, and modify COPY start.sh /start.sh to COPY start.sh ../start.sh (maybe this script needs to be in that directory)

The effect of the cd only lasts for the current RUN command. The next RUN will start from the current WORKDIR.

Try also to add: VOLUME /config before setting the ENV for HOME.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i try it with WORKDIR and i get the same damn error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448682/cmake-error-the-source-does-not-appear-to-contain-cmakelists-txt/52068568; https://github.com/apngasm/apngasm/issues/68 ; https://github.com/lyricat/Hotot/issues/568 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029174/cmake-error-the-source-directory-home-pi-opencv-3-0-0-build-build-examples-on ; Check this links. May help

Comment: okay. i fix the problem. I have seperate the git clone and mkdir commands in own RUN commands. Thank you Razvan for your help and input!