# Trying to run cmake .. command

Tags: git, cmake

I am trying to run `cmake ..` in git bash, but getting following error:

```
Yoinab Tech@DESKTOP-I5NBB38 MINGW64 ~/build
$ cmake ..
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/Yoinab Tech" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

How can I get past this error message?

Comment: Is there a CMakeLists.txt file in C:/Users/Yoinab Tech?

Comment: @StephenNewell,No.

Comment: What happens when you run the command and provide an appropriate path?

Comment: @StephenNewell, what I did is that 
first i made directory like "build" then cd build then run command cmake .. then getting above error. in git bash.

Comment: The `..` is supposed to be a path to your source folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake error 'the source does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448682/cmake-error-the-source-does-not-appear-to-contain-cmakelists-txt)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `..` (in `cmake ..`) by the relative path where your `CMakeLists.txt` is.

```
cmake ../path/to-CMakeLists.txt
```

(as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52068568/6309), for instance)