# installing OpenCV on centos 8

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, centos

I'm trying to install `opencv` on my `centos8` server and use it in my `java` program. I followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-8/), but when I change directory to `/opencv/build` folder and run

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D 
INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D 
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

,I get the following error:

> CMake Error: The source directory "/root/opencv_build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

how to solve this issue? the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448682/cmake-error-the-source-does-not-appear-to-contain-cmakelists-txt/52068568) didn't help.

Comment: When running `cmake` command with `..` as the last parameter from `/opencv/build` directory, the **source directory** should be `/opencv`. But the error message tells about `/root/opencv_build` as source directory. It seems you **actually** do different things...

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is exactly what confuses me! I don't understand why it searches for the file in `/root/opencv_build` and not in `/root/opencv_build/opencv`. what mistake may have I made?!

Comment: Well, before running `cmake` run `pwd` and check that it prints **exactly** `/root/opencv_build/opencv/build`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it exactly prints `/root/opencv_build/opencv/build`!

Comment: the problem was the contents of cmake cache file which were pointing to wrong directories. I deleted the cache file and it worked!

Comment: Ok, so you have you run some commands which are not described in the tutorial. Next time it is better to store somewhere the exact commands you have entered. And if these fail, then you will be able paste these commands into the question post.